# Constructing an XML tag for pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, xml-parsing, pom.xml

I am creating a maven `<reporting>` tag using [org.apache.maven.model.Reporting](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Reporting.html) class. I am trying to construct a tag like

**Expected Output Tag**

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>            
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

The **code** I use to achieve the same is,

```
ReportPlugin reportPlugin = new ReportPlugin();
reportPlugin.setGroupId("org.codehaus.mojo");
reportPlugin.setArtifactId("cobertura-maven-plugin");
Reporting reporting = new Reporting();
reporting.addPlugin(reportPlugin);
```

But the **output tag** I get is,

```
<reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>false</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>                
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I do not see a `plugin` tag like <`plugins><plugin>......</plugin></plugins>` but I get only a `<plugins>......</plugins>` in the output I have shown above. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to see if I get the same results.
The code I used is below:

```
    Model model = new Model();
    ReportPlugin reportPlugin = new ReportPlugin();
    reportPlugin.setGroupId("org.codehaus.mojo");
    reportPlugin.setArtifactId("cobertura-maven-plugin");
    Reporting reporting = new Reporting();
    reporting.addPlugin(reportPlugin);
    model.setReporting(reporting);
    
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    MavenXpp3Writer xpp = new MavenXpp3Writer();
    try {
        xpp.write(writer, model);
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code produced the following output:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

I used the embedded Maven version (3.2.1/1.5.1.20150109-1819) of Eclipse Luna.
The POM I used has the following dependencies:

> maven-reporting-api: 3.0-alpha-2
>
> maven-model: 3.2.5

I hope this helps.